# Android Google Vision API problems

Tags: android, google-vision

Sometime and not in all devices, Vision library of Google returns false in the isOperational function. I've tried to free space in phone (it has 44 GB free space), change network, uninstall/reinstall but never works.
I've seen even the folder /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files where gms store files when download it, but is empty.
The only thing that works for me is clear Google Play Services data.
So, I think that is not a problem of space but Google Play Services that have corrupted files. 
Have you this problem? I spend a lot of time but I don't found a solution.
The error the gives me is:

```
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module 
com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.barcode:0 and remote module 
com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.barcode:0
D/BarcodeNativeHandle: Cannot load feature, fall back to load whole module.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
I/Vision: Loading library libbarhopper.so
libbarhopper.so library load status: false
```

The relevant gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
```

The relevant manifest part

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="barcode"/>
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue ?

Comment: in production i've not seen already this error....are you in debug mode?

Comment: Yes in debug mode